# inverse power spectrum FFT

Tags: matlab

I want to run my code that is about Speech Enhancement
Based on Deep Neural Networks and our step is
1-framing signal * hamming window
2-log-power spectral frame
3-Deep learning
4-inverse output to signal
so my problem is inversing can not return true answer
I want to s=out(:) 
my code

```
  function [ out ] = dfft( s )


  N=300;
   M=20;
   L=length(s);

  NumFram=floor(L/(N-M))-1;
    frames=zeros(NumFram,N);
  for i=1:N

      frames(1,i)=s(i);

   end
   j=1;


  for j=2:NumFram
  n=1;

  for i= (j-1) * (N-M) : (j-1) * (N-M) + N

  frames(j,n)=s(i);
    n=n+1;


 end
 end

 frames(:,N+1)=[];


 HamiW=zeros(1,N);
 HamW=hamming(N);

for i=1:N
HamiW(1,i)=HamW(i);
end


Y=zeros(NumFram,N);

Y=frames*diag(HamiW);

 FFT=zeros(NumFram,N);


 for i=1:NumFram

    FFT(i,:)=fft(Y(i,:));
      for j=1:N
        phase(i,j)=atan(imag(FFT(i,j))/real(FFT(i,j)));
        logfft(i,j)=FFT(i,j)*conj(FFT(i,j));
         Z=sqrt(logfft(i,j));
         S(i,j)= complex(Z*cos(phase(i,j)),Z*sin(phase(i,j)));


 end
out(i,:)=ifft(S(i,:));

end





end
```

Comment: What is the question/error?

Comment: when I run inversing log-power spectral and output is complex number!

Comment: what about `s=real(ifft(S))`?

Comment: I testsed real(ifft(S)) but I hear only noise

Comment: Try to add some more information and maybe post the question here http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The power spectrum does not contain phase information. It is therefore not possible to reconstruct the signal from the power spectrum alone.